# NSString returning jibberish

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Totally lost with this one. Here's my code:

```
theColor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"white"];
NSLog(@"%s", theColor);
```

Which is returing:

```
†t†å
```

I must be doing something stupid, but can not figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your print to:

```
NSLog(@"%@", theColor);
```

Hope it helps.

The thing is that `%s` expects a C-string (char array with a NULL terminator) and you are passing a `NSString` instance which is not the same as a C-string. The modifier you need in a format to print `NSString` content is `%@`.

Answer (score 4):

`%s` is for printing C-style strings.

`%@` is for printing Objective-C objects (like NSString).

Answer (score 0):

BTW: “theColor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"white"];” – why not “theColor = @"white";”?

Greetings